# How to persist entities, how to create table from entities without "main class"?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

I'm developing an application, and I started with creating my JPA entities (annotation + persistence.xml). Then in my persistence.xml file, I created a connection for a MySql data base (the connection is fine).

The problem is that I just don't know how to persist my entities without creating a "main class".

Do I have to run my main class for every single entity that I'm going to create?

Comment: what do you mean 'without main class'? What should trigger the creation of the entity?

Comment: with a java EE container of course.. i mean i have to have a main class to do the persisting thing?

Comment: And what does EntityManager#persist say?

Comment: @Nadia: you're building a JEE application. This application probably have a UI, implememented as a web application. The entities will be created when the end users will use the web application, click links and submitting forms, which will call the methods of services (EJBs) which will in turn use the JPA API to persist entities. Your question really sounds like you don't know what you're doing. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

To persist an entity, you need an instance of entityManager. Since you have a Java EE container you can get an instance of entityManager using the annotation `@PersistenceContext` in *some bean*

What I mean by *some bean* ? It's a bean managed by the Java EE container. So, for instance you have to define a bean like this :

```
@Stateless
public class MyController{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persistIt(Object anEntity){
        em.persist(anEntity);
    }
}
```

The annotation `@Stateless` indicate to the container that it must manage this class and take care of providing an instance of the entityManager when needed.

So to answer precisely to your question: it is not mandatory to have another class to persist an entity, as soon as you find a way to get access to an entityManager instance.

**But**:

- it is definitively NOT a best practice.
- to take advantages of entityManager injection: you must use another managed bean so that entityManager can be injected by the container.

Additionally, the controller is where you can handle your transactions properly.